# How to treat first and last row of a subset differently using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have `data.frame` that looks like this (export for trial at the end of question):

```
   vehicleRefId dep_time trav_time start_link end_link arr_time
1            10    39956       119     270549   937360    40075
2            10    41756       413     937360   212265    42169
3            10    42656       565     212265   184658    43221
4            10    47156       184     184658   357020    47340
5            10    49556       506     357020   976840    50062
6            10    50156       787     976840   132606    50943
7            10    55556      1177     132606   708563    56733
8            10    56156       210     708563   568677    56366
9            10    61556      2965     568677   270549    64521
10      1000157    25473      1940     557064   336850    27413
11      1000157    47114       136     336850   141230    47250
12      1000157    60014       934     141230   545278    60948
13      1000183    26639      1543     592921   655099    28182
14      1000183    73014       622     656482   815987    73636
15      1000183    79506      1290     815987   545278    80796
```

My goal is to have a `data.frame` which tells me, from what time on `arr_time` and for how long `duration` (`dep_time[row=n+1] - arr_time[row=n]`) a vehicle is at a `link`.

The tricky part is that the operation to extract this information needs to be done for every `vehicleRefId` separately, and the respective first and last row needs to be treated differently from the middle rows.

The first row per `vehicleRefId`, the link to be extracted is the `start_link` and the time to be extracted is the `dep_time`. Then the first row needs to be treated like a middle row (mode detail in the desired output below).

For the last row, I need the `end_link` and for the duration, the delta of  `max(df$arr_time)` and `arr_time`.

The desired output:

```
    link        arr_time    duration
1   270549      0           40075   #first row: start_link | 0 | dep_time
2   937360      40075       1681    #middle rows: end_link |arr_time | dep_time of next row - current row arr_time
3   212265      42169       2094    
4   184658      43221       1052
...
10  270549      64521       52006   #last row: end_link |arr_time| max(arr_time)-arr_time
11  557064      0           25473   #first row: start_link | 0 | dep_time
12  336850      27413       19701   #middle rows: end_link |arr_time | dep_time of next row - current row arr_time
...
```

Data to test:

```
structure(list(vehicleRefId = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 1000157L, 1000157L, 1000157L, 1000183L, 1000183L, 
1000183L, 1000252L, 1000252L, 1000567L, 1000567L, 1000568L, 1000568L, 
1000568L, 1000568L, 100060L, 100060L, 100060L, 100060L, 100060L, 
100060L, 100060L, 100061L, 100061L, 1000670L, 1000670L, 1000670L, 
1000928L, 1000928L, 100098L, 100098L, 100098L, 100098L, 100099L, 
100099L, 1000999L, 1000999L, 1000999L, 1001004L, 1001004L, 1001004L, 
1001004L, 1001005L, 1001005L, 100102L, 100102L, 100103L, 100103L, 
1001046L, 1001046L, 1001046L, 1001090L, 1001090L, 1001090L, 1001090L, 
1001090L, 1001090L, 1001174L, 1001174L, 1001232L, 1001232L, 100126L, 
100126L, 100126L, 100126L, 100126L, 100126L, 100126L, 100126L, 
100128L, 100128L, 100128L, 100128L, 100128L, 1001313L, 1001313L, 
1001313L, 1001313L, 1001313L, 1001313L, 1001313L, 1001313L, 1001349L, 
1001349L, 1001388L, 1001388L, 1001456L, 1001456L, 100149L, 100149L, 
100149L, 100150L, 100150L, 1001541L, 1001541L, 1001541L, 1001565L, 
1001565L, 1001565L, 1001768L, 1001768L, 1001787L, 1001787L, 1001787L, 
1001957L, 1001957L, 1001957L, 1001957L, 1001957L, 1001957L, 1001995L, 
1001995L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002060L, 1002060L, 100222L, 100222L, 
1002277L, 1002277L, 1002277L, 1002279L, 1002279L, 1002279L, 1002279L, 
10024L, 10024L, 10024L, 10024L, 10024L, 10024L, 1002404L, 1002404L, 
1002443L, 1002443L, 100254L, 100254L, 100254L, 100254L, 100254L, 
100254L, 100254L, 1002576L, 1002576L, 10026L, 10026L, 10026L, 
10026L, 10026L, 1002607L, 1002607L, 100277L, 100277L, 1002772L, 
1002772L, 100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 
100284L, 1002844L, 1002844L, 1002844L, 1002844L, 1002871L, 1002871L, 
1002938L, 1002938L, 1002938L, 1002938L, 1002938L, 1003015L, 1003015L, 
10031L, 10031L, 10031L, 10031L, 10032L, 10032L, 10032L, 1003414L, 
1003414L, 100352L, 100352L, 1003611L, 1003611L, 1003699L, 1003699L, 
1003699L), dep_time = c(39956, 41756, 42656, 47156, 49556, 50156, 
55556, 56156, 61556, 25473, 47114, 60014, 26639, 73014, 79506, 
64194, 66047, 80817, 80901, 27402, 31547, 36647, 43847, 30627, 
36927, 43227, 44187, 46827, 65727, 67527, 51986, 56595, 21346, 
67159, 72774, 21263, 60858, 31959, 37359, 39759, 41559, 61889, 
74682, 21065, 21261, 56661, 22111, 22362, 59409, 59494, 32070, 
63829, 26169, 59769, 53159, 57026, 69595, 71304, 72284, 17744, 
17995, 52236, 59460, 60499, 60584, 28153, 41635, 33821, 64393, 
33929, 35729, 36449, 48329, 50594, 52829, 62122, 62231, 27002, 
27122, 54902, 67502, 70202, 26021, 26787, 45267, 56712, 59667, 
63867, 74067, 77067, 20674, 41721, 21935, 56252, 44903, 48563, 
25796, 26876, 69896, 57837, 72620, 30899, 30997, 31311, 53403, 
58235, 63635, 48169, 76477, 51616, 66370, 67270, 26978, 27230, 
27333, 59126, 59513, 59608, 24985, 62204, 28491, 29787, 34216, 
45639, 81496, 51318, 59664, 48649, 49563, 52563, 22525, 34077, 
49559, 67677, 30877, 34348, 59977, 60208, 63877, 64108, 17836, 
53183, 29505, 43327, 27293, 44377, 45090, 48893, 67777, 68977, 
69800, 67967, 115984, 35174, 35465, 44893, 60845, 62045, 39345, 
43670, 22401, 67411, 26924, 58472, 40117, 41920, 48445, 58085, 
61161, 64385, 66058, 37909, 39969, 48994, 54394, 33921, 79759, 
25356, 28094, 42794, 48194, 67094, 30509, 39139, 44936, 46462, 
72425, 80962, 25488, 53534, 55427, 29876, 40714, 51083, 53335, 
47371, 48622, 25640, 30665, 34265), trav_time = c(119, 413, 565, 
184, 506, 787, 1177, 210, 2965, 1940, 136, 934, 1543, 622, 1290, 
2781, 1859, 54, 214, 89, 463, 943, 1536, 565, 461, 279, 800, 
820, 1113, 1344, 214, 205, 991, 314, 29, 1186, 1316, 491, 529, 
572, 346, 89, 110, 402, 953, 1211, 394, 49, 54, 481, 2093, 2139, 
1406, 1650, 135, 119, 1693, 1187, 49, 255, 49, 602, 1705, 54, 
229, 934, 632, 707, 689, 491, 222, 353, 205, 493, 238, 39, 191, 
182, 2249, 1083, 669, 917, 1377, 372, 972, 1515, 351, 668, 348, 
618, 817, 1021, 971, 874, 685, 425, 407, 178, 251, 296, 230, 
32, 93, 129, 325, 631, 707, 1075, 830, 1828, 1167, 1319, 768, 
49, 539, 611, 36, 258, 2258, 1939, 2020, 49, 2120, 842, 575, 
246, 270, 387, 615, 631, 164, 556, 151, 569, 249, 283, 237, 279, 
1073, 1693, 564, 578, 1611, 1458, 1463, 1097, 0, 1076, 881, 737, 
0, 1645, 543, 237, 271, 1640, 1494, 1257, 369, 442, 112, 151, 
2361, 2370, 757, 682, 290, 541, 409, 839, 11, 1975, 1060, 118, 
1441, 1985, 1468, 1495, 376, 426, 421, 699, 755, 559, 1865, 1677, 
712, 648, 1045, 633, 105, 2552, 1925, 84, 101, 88, 472, 3229, 
794, 706), start_link = c(270549L, 937360L, 212265L, 184658L, 
357020L, 976840L, 132606L, 708563L, 568677L, 557064L, 336850L, 
141230L, 592921L, 656482L, 815987L, 444204L, 529184L, 293993L, 
924069L, 743566L, 988492L, 447485L, 243378L, 442424L, 880219L, 
553505L, 307420L, 475317L, 880219L, 137882L, 442424L, 1044971L, 
444204L, 715959L, 862183L, 444204L, 86208L, 518340L, 880806L, 
390902L, 1057392L, 518340L, 557064L, 444204L, 277196L, 937812L, 
444204L, 924041L, 293993L, 924069L, 444204L, 173355L, 207844L, 
488357L, 207844L, 921742L, 444204L, 322842L, 924041L, 444204L, 
924041L, 208359L, 917289L, 293993L, 924069L, 921742L, 44740L, 
592921L, 1031555L, 715194L, 880261L, 444044L, 715194L, 444204L, 
589007L, 685965L, 921742L, 715194L, 527966L, 352143L, 814122L, 
69948L, 921742L, 261041L, 887737L, 943525L, 219773L, 887737L, 
629352L, 887737L, 444204L, 726443L, 444204L, 541592L, 86208L, 
89636L, 442424L, 229666L, 598571L, 442424L, 1044971L, 921742L, 
731278L, 208365L, 444204L, 773893L, 522604L, 444204L, 911454L, 
557064L, 340254L, 179635L, 444204L, 924041L, 1043759L, 325682L, 
690654L, 924069L, 444204L, 717241L, 943525L, 924041L, 770275L, 
921742L, 383765L, 586665L, 921742L, 444204L, 273230L, 136011L, 
921742L, 518320L, 1044971L, 518320L, 390783L, 270549L, 390783L, 
270549L, 390783L, 712438L, 444204L, 771873L, 557064L, 656482L, 
511889L, 199293L, 511889L, 511889L, 199293L, 656098L, 511889L, 
444204L, 313216L, 390783L, 270549L, 550473L, 417690L, 493221L, 
921742L, 289147L, 153483L, 1044971L, 557064L, 5297L, 685965L, 
86208L, 511889L, 430753L, 592921L, 428902L, 921742L, 444204L, 
682408L, 913467L, 693061L, 557064L, 361930L, 444204L, 892054L, 
711951L, 181348L, 711951L, 592921L, 338950L, 550473L, 1006099L, 
943525L, 577067L, 550473L, 1027040L, 8378L, 444204L, 221998L, 
706467L, 724076L, 557064L, 624565L, 444204L, 423728L, 61536L), 
    end_link = c(937360L, 212265L, 184658L, 357020L, 976840L, 
    132606L, 708563L, 568677L, 270549L, 336850L, 141230L, 545278L, 
    655099L, 815987L, 545278L, 529184L, 545278L, 924124L, 545278L, 
    988492L, 447485L, 243378L, 592922L, 880219L, 553505L, 307420L, 
    475317L, 880219L, 137882L, 442424L, 921743L, 442424L, 655099L, 
    862183L, 229128L, 322843L, 557063L, 880806L, 390902L, 1057392L, 
    518340L, 557063L, 518340L, 277196L, 937812L, 557063L, 924040L, 
    294688L, 924124L, 545278L, 173355L, 545278L, 488357L, 207844L, 
    921743L, 207844L, 322843L, 924040L, 294688L, 924040L, 294688L, 
    917289L, 1043758L, 924124L, 545278L, 44740L, 545278L, 1031555L, 
    545278L, 880261L, 444044L, 715194L, 921743L, 589007L, 511890L, 
    921743L, 715194L, 527966L, 352143L, 814122L, 69948L, 715194L, 
    261041L, 887737L, 558366L, 219773L, 887737L, 629352L, 887737L, 
    545278L, 726443L, 545278L, 541592L, 545278L, 89636L, 545278L, 
    229666L, 598571L, 442424L, 557063L, 442424L, 685966L, 208365L, 
    921743L, 773893L, 522604L, 557063L, 911454L, 545278L, 340254L, 
    179635L, 545278L, 924040L, 294688L, 325682L, 276534L, 648084L, 
    545278L, 717241L, 545278L, 924040L, 294688L, 558366L, 383765L, 
    545278L, 921743L, 586665L, 273230L, 136011L, 545278L, 518320L, 
    545278L, 518320L, 545278L, 270549L, 390784L, 270549L, 390784L, 
    712438L, 390784L, 771873L, 545278L, 655099L, 545278L, 199293L, 
    511890L, 511889L, 199293L, 656098L, 511890L, 511889L, 313216L, 
    545278L, 270549L, 390784L, 417690L, 493221L, 390784L, 289147L, 
    921743L, 921743L, 153483L, 5297L, 545278L, 1006143L, 511890L, 
    430753L, 592922L, 428902L, 1045458L, 685966L, 682407L, 913467L, 
    693061L, 545278L, 361930L, 545278L, 892054L, 711951L, 181348L, 
    711951L, 545278L, 338950L, 592922L, 1006099L, 558366L, 577067L, 
    558366L, 1027040L, 913135L, 550472L, 222013L, 545278L, 724077L, 
    706467L, 624565L, 545278L, 423728L, 61536L, 423728L), arr_time = c(40075, 
    42169, 43221, 47340, 50062, 50943, 56733, 56366, 64521, 27413, 
    47250, 60948, 28182, 73636, 80796, 66975, 67906, 80871, 81115, 
    27491, 32010, 37590, 45383, 31192, 37388, 43506, 44987, 47647, 
    66840, 68871, 52200, 56800, 22337, 67473, 72803, 22449, 62174, 
    32450, 37888, 40331, 41905, 61978, 74792, 21467, 22214, 57872, 
    22505, 22411, 59463, 59975, 34163, 65968, 27575, 61419, 53294, 
    57145, 71288, 72491, 72333, 17999, 18044, 52838, 61165, 60553, 
    60813, 29087, 42267, 34528, 65082, 34420, 35951, 36802, 48534, 
    51087, 53067, 62161, 62422, 27184, 29371, 55985, 68171, 71119, 
    27398, 27159, 46239, 58227, 60018, 64535, 74415, 77685, 21491, 
    42742, 22906, 57126, 45588, 48988, 26203, 27054, 70147, 58133, 
    72850, 30931, 31090, 31440, 53728, 58866, 64342, 49244, 77307, 
    53444, 67537, 68589, 27746, 27279, 27872, 59737, 59549, 59866, 
    27243, 64143, 30511, 29836, 36336, 46481, 82071, 51564, 59934, 
    49036, 50178, 53194, 22689, 34633, 49710, 68246, 31126, 34631, 
    60214, 60487, 64950, 65801, 18400, 53761, 31116, 44785, 28756, 
    45474, 45090, 49969, 68658, 69714, 69800, 69612, 116527, 
    35411, 35736, 46533, 62339, 63302, 39714, 44112, 22513, 67562, 
    29285, 60842, 40874, 42602, 48735, 58626, 61570, 65224, 66069, 
    39884, 41029, 49112, 55835, 35906, 81227, 26851, 28470, 43220, 
    48615, 67793, 31264, 39698, 46801, 48139, 73137, 81610, 26533, 
    54167, 55532, 32428, 42639, 51167, 53436, 47459, 49094, 28869, 
    31459, 34971)), row.names = c(NA, 200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'vehicleRefId' and get the difference betweeen the `lag` of 'arr_time' and 'dep_time' to create the new columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(vehicleRefId) %>%
  transmute(link = start_link, new_arr_time = lag(arr_time, default = 0), 
           duration = replace(dep_time - lag(arr_time), 1, first(arr_time)) ) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, the last row is not executed properly. In the last row per group, the ```link``` should be the ```end_link``` and the ```duration``` is the ```max(arr_time)-arr_time```.  Furthermore, how is the  ```1``` in ```replace()``` to be interpreted?

Comment: @YvesR the `1` is the index for the first row for each group

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
output <- setDT(DF)[, .(
        link = shift(end_link, fill=start_link[1L]),
        arr_time = shift(arr_time, fill=0L),
        duration = c(dep_time[1L], 
            #dep_time of next row - current row arr_time
            (shift(dep_time, -1L) - arr_time)[-c(1L, .N)], 
            max(arr_time) - arr_time[.N])
    ), vehicleRefId]
```

`output[vehicleRefId==10L]`:

```
   vehicleRefId   link arr_time duration
1:           10 270549        0    39956
2:           10 937360    40075      487
3:           10 212265    42169     3935
4:           10 184658    43221     2216
5:           10 357020    47340       94
6:           10 976840    50062     4613
7:           10 132606    50943     -577
8:           10 708563    56733     5190
9:           10 568677    56366        0
```

`DF[vehicleRefId==10]`:

```
   vehicleRefId dep_time trav_time start_link end_link arr_time
1:           10    39956       119     270549   937360    40075
2:           10    41756       413     937360   212265    42169
3:           10    42656       565     212265   184658    43221
4:           10    47156       184     184658   357020    47340
5:           10    49556       506     357020   976840    50062
6:           10    50156       787     976840   132606    50943
7:           10    55556      1177     132606   708563    56733
8:           10    56156       210     708563   568677    56366
9:           10    61556      2965     568677   270549    64521
```